# How can I use PlotTheme and FrameTicks correctly together?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot some data. When I normally do it, there are a lot of zeros in the y-axis values which does not make any sense. So previously I was fixing the problem using `FrameTicks`. However, it seems it does not work when you are using the `PlotTheme` at the same time.

How can I remove the unnecessary zeros from left side of the plot when I am using the `PlotTheme`?

```
ListLinePlot[Re@LabFr[[;; 4000, 1, 2]], PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All},
 DataRange -> {0, 4000 0.01},
 PlotLegends -> {"code stress x1x1", "None"},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, {0.4, 0.2, 0.0, -0.2, -0.4, -0.6}}, {{0,
     5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, Automatic}},
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "\[Pi]_12"} ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the settings for FrameTicks is

```
FrameTicks -> {{left,right},{bottom,top}}
```

If you want the left y axis to have the same frame ticks as the right, you could do

```
FrameTicks -> {{{0.4, 0.2, 0.0, -0.2, -0.4, -0.6}, {0.4, 0.2, 0.0, -0.2, -0.4, -0.6}}, 
               {{0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25}, Automatic}}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help Kloppy. It perfectly works.